# How can I mount a hard drive with read/write permissions for all the users listed on the Linux server?

Tags: mount, sudo

Two users `user1` and `user2` are registered on the server, both with `sudo` access.

`user1` mounted a hard drive with:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda /media/user1/DATA
$ ll /media/user1
total 12K
drwx------ 19 user1 user1 4.0K 2020-01-25 23:44:42 DATA
```

How can we make sure that `user2` has access to `/media/user1/DATA`?

No need to have a solution that persists upon reboot (for example editing `/etc/fstab`), nor something like `chmod -R 777` on all the files on this hard drive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer on: https://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-configure-access-control-lists-acls-setfacl-getfacl-linux/

With Linux, there is something called ACL: Access Control Lists. So to solve my problem, I ran:

```
setfacl -m u:user2:rwx /media/user1/DATA
```

After running this command, `user2` had access to `/media/user1/DATA`.

To list the ACL of a directory, simply do:

```
getfacl /path/to/dir
```